# Add image before embedded video

Tags: video, embed, gif

I am trying to place the above image for the player below.

This is what I got so far. I would like the gif to go above the embedded video, so when played, it can start loading.

```
 <div id="video"><img src="images/hand.gif" width="500" height="281" />

 <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/66167649" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do you could use some JS to hide the video until the image is clicked.

```
<a href="#" id="video" class="show_hide">
    <img src="images/hand.gif" width="500" height="281" />
</a>

<div class="slidingDiv">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/66167649" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Make sure to reference jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $("#video").hide();
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Still having trouble trying to actually get it work without it being separate.

Comment: Have you got a link to the page you're developing?

Answer (score 0):

> I ended up figuring out what was wrong. So basically, you can't do it unless using some JS just like you stated. Also make sure that the vimeo video whichever you decide to use, has an autoplay variable of 1, otherwise, no matter how perfect you can get it; it will never play.

```
  <div id="video"><a href="#" id="showVideo"><img src="images/hand.gif" width="647" height="366" />
```

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"          type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">


    $('#showVideo').click(function () {
    $('#video').fadeIn().html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/66167649?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=d01e2f&amp;autoplay=1" width="647" height="366" align="middle" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>');
$("#showVideo").hide()

  });
  </script>
```